# Chemistry Experiment with Chametz on Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, hanaah-benefit

If one is in a school environment where he/she has a chemistry lab/lab exam on Chol Hamoed Pesach that they must attend (putting the question of doing this on Chol Hamoed aside), and the lab exercise requires use of ethanol (such as in an [esterification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ester) reaction, which can combine a carboxylic acid and alcohol), would it be Halachically appropriate to perform this experiment on Pesach?  For the sake of this question, let us assume that we are required to use ethanol which is made from fermented grain and distilled, but still drinkable at this point.

Comment: I think the question "boils down" (no pun, here) to whether you own the ethanol or not. In a college lab, you probably don't own any of the chemicals, so I don't sense a problem. However, it's possible that if they give you all the chemicals before the lab and the prof. says, use these to conduct your own experiment, you may have acquired ownership. Offhand, it seems that if you have a Gentile lab partner with you, and he does the experiments, you may get around the problem.

Comment: Excellent points, but what if you pay for materials at the beginning of the course?

Comment: If you have paid for all lab materials at the beginning of the year, then, you own all the materials already even if you don't physically have it, now. How would that be different than paying for a "pie of the month" club? Two ways you may be able to circumvent the problem - if you sell your Pesach share of the lab in advance to a Gentile (ask a rav about the technicalities of doing this) or if you had the alcohol before Pesach and in some fashion made it inedible. Of course, a simple method may be, in a college, to do the experiment before or after Pesach.

Comment: Most of the ethanol used in labs is synthetic, and so not hametz. I clearly remember, about 37 years ago, that there was a winchester of ethanol (from Frutarom) that _was_  marked "hametz" with a stamp on the label. From this it can be understood that the manufacturer specifically indicated the status as special to distinguish it from other batches of ethanol (the vast majority). However, IF the ONLY ethanol available is marked as hametz, then at first sight there would be a prohibition to *benefit* from it from the Torah. (Isur hana'ah mideoraita).

Comment: @Epicentre you are very likely correct, but for the sake of this question, we are assuming it is chametz (as I stated above), and asking if that issur hanaah applies to this case

Comment: @DanF I believe it is forbidden to benefit from chametz even if you do not own it

Comment: @wfb You are correct with this. And, it does seem that you are obtaining some form of benefit from the lab experiment as you are being graded for the results and I assume that as a student, you need to submit some report based on the results. Maybe, to get around this, if your lab partner does all the experimentation, and handles the chometz and you base your reports on his measurements. And, what if after the ethanol was mixed with other chemicals so it is now inedible? Can you handle the chemical mixture at this point? It's not chametz, now.

Comment: I don’t know much about this type of chemistry. At what point during the experiment does it ferment? Is it only after it’s mixed, or is it already Chametz by the time you bring it to the lab? In the case where it only ferments after, are we assuming that you are required to sustain the molecule for more than 18 minutes, so that it fully ferments, or is 18 minutes not required in these types of interactions?

Comment: @DonielF It is presumably already Chametz by the time you bring it to the lab.  Not sure of the exact halachos.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות So since we’re both unsure, I’ve gone ahead and [asked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91025/9682) the question.

Comment: This sounds like it is asking for a practical ruling. Perhaps edit the question to make it about the concepts rather than about the specific case. (I can't vote to close because it has an active bounty.)