# what is chimutz chemichaly?

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven

distantly related: [Is chimutz a wholly physical phenomenon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56987/is-chimutz-a-wholly-physical-phenomenon)
I searched but could not find a question like this on the site but here it goes. Has there been any understanding of what חימוץ is? Meaning in actuality do we know what chemical reaction makes something chometz?
Dough Rising. If yeast is put in it, one who makes rice bread and other legumes bread it rises.
Sourdough, there is GF sourdough started made from rice flour.
Dough cracking – I think I have seen in GF dough
Clearly, these are not signs of chimutz, as chimutz only applies to the five grains.

Comment: Does yeast in rice flour dough really make it rise significantly? I think any celiac will tell you that it's not the same.

Comment: Then why is wheat bread still ubiquitous? "nicely" and "rise significantly" are very ambiguous terms, but the facts on the ground seem clear that gluten free "bread" is not equivalent.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91004/why-are-oats-chametz-if-oats-cannot-rise#comment295235_91004 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91025/when-does-ethanol-become-chametz#comment295313_91025

Comment: Again "a lot" is very imprecise. Does it create an equivalent product to wheat or barley? Seemingly it's not just the flavor of wheat vs rice (both very very subtle flavors) since people like rice flavor in rice cakes and oat flavor in oatmeal and no one dreams of wheat cakes being 10x better

Comment: I deleted my previous comments. I agree that it might not be the same. so I understand your answer would be chimutz means rising to level x. what is X?

Comment: IMHO we can only give it a legal definition, not a chemical one.

Comment: I don't know what X is (and the [aruch hashulchan](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.453.5) argues none of us do and that's why we have to be so strict) but it's something that in principle is definitely physically testable since they did a test in the gemara to see if rice could become chametz א"ר יוחנן בן נורי באה היא לידי מצה וחמץ.  ורבנין אמרי אינה באה לידי מצה וחמץ.  ויבדקוה.  על עיקר בדיקתה הן חלוקין.  ריב"נ אמר בדקוה ומצאוה שהיא באה לידי מצה וחמץ.  ורבנין אמרי בדקוה ולא מצאו אותו שהיא באה לידי מצה וחמץ.